# argument out of range before create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a text field in new form:

```
 <%= f.text_field :date_start, class: "form-control", id: "date_start" %>
```

The text in the text field is formatted like this:

```
"08/29/2014 12:00 am"
```

I want to submit it to create action and parse it as such:

```
formatted_params[:date_start] = Date.strptime(formatted_params[:date_start],
                                              '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
```

In Rails console this parsing worked fine:

```
> DateTime.strptime("08/20/2014 4:00 pm",'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
=> Wed, 20 Aug 2014 16:00:00 +0000
```

Unfortunately raise raises the following error before the controller create action is called and I have a chance to parse it:

```
argument out of range
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb
    #   Time.zone.parse('22:30:00') # => Fri, 31 Dec 1999 22:30:00 HST -10:00
    def parse(str, now=now)
      parts = Date._parse(str, false)
      return if parts.empty?
      time = Time.new(
        parts.fetch(:year, now.year),
        parts.fetch(:mon, now.month),
        parts.fetch(:mday, now.day),
        parts.fetch(:hour, 0),
        parts.fetch(:min, 0),
```

How can I handle the parsing instead of Rails here?

Comment: One option is probably to use text_field_tag rather than the form_for text method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `date_start=` setter to add your own date parsing. In the model you are setting the date_start attribute on, add a method for `date_start=`:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def date_start=(s)
    datetime = DateTime.strptime(s,'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
    write_attribute :date_start, datetime
  end
end
```

Comment: But if I modify this setter, when I render an edit form, will it still show the value of the date for the record? I remember having a problem before when overriding attributes, when you view edit form, the values are no longer present.

Comment: Yes, it will still show it correctly, because it's modifying the setter, not the getter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/stringify_date
It's create virtual attributes:

```rb
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  stringify :date_start, format: '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p'
end

# This generates:
m = MyModel.new
m.date_start_string = "08/20/2014 4:00 pm"
m.date_start
=> Wed, 20 Aug 2014 16:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: I don't think you need a gem for something trivial like this.